# Why val() work on a list but an attribute does not?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

This is my coffeescript

```
name     = @$ '#require-name'
console.log name.val()
```

Apparently `name` is a list of element. However the `val()` can correctly return the value held by the only element in the list.

But if I want to get the value of an attribute of this element, I get `undefined`. Why is this?

[image]

In other part of the code I want to refer to this element `#require-name` alone. So I write this as

```
name     = @$('#require-name')[0]
```

It does not feel very elegant to me. I want to do away the indexing (`[0]`) since there will only be this one element. Is there a better way to express this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#require-name')` returns you jQuery object thus `.val()` is used for fetching the values. Where as `@$('#require-name')[0]` return you underlying DOM element thus you can access properties like `name.checked`

Or, You can use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method

```
$('#require-name').prop('checked')
```

Comment: I would like to understand why `val()` works in the first place... Is it a jquery magic?